# Allighning cell renderer for treeview in GTK2 won't work

Tags: treeview, gtk, alignment, pygtk

I'm trying to build some program with GTK and python.

I've created the GUI in glade, and assigned a model for the treeview. THen When i set the alignment in the cell renderer, it doesn't work

The model type of the column is gchararrray, the cell renderer type is text. I generate the data from sqlite and then pass it to listEntry.append(), the column in question is string.

Here is a screen shot from glade[image]:

Here is a screen shot from my programm(it's the column suma):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set its "Horizontal Alignment" from 0.0 to 1.0